# How to smooth multiple vertices at a point?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I know this is **very** simple, but I've tried using the smooth button in the mesh tools section, but it won't work:
Before:
[image: http://snag.gy/1fdy6.jpg]

This is with smooth vertex:
[image: http://snag.gy/QMFve.jpg]

What should I do?

Thanks in advance
(I need to smoothen it so much that it is only a nice curve: http://snag.gy/O1kk7.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool is working, you just need more geometry and bump up the number of times to smooth the mesh.

[image]

---

So the tool works but I doubt it will give you the results you are looking for. It's best if you model this curved bit by just add some supporting edge rings through the top of you mesh and moving these outwards.

[image]

Later as your model gets more refined, you can add a *Subsurf* modifier and some supporting loops along the edges to get a nice sleek look.

[image]

***NB:*** It's best to get the basic outline/shape of your model down before adding any deformation modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to add the subdivision modifier. Then you probably have to tweak your geometry to get the shape you want. You will see the updates in realtime.

Starting geometry, very lowpoly:

[image: lowpoly geometry]

Subdivision modifier added. Adjust subdivision to reach sufficient smoothness. Be sure to set render higher or equal to view.

[image: added subdivision]

Add loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to make some edges more pronounced. You can also select an edge in edit mode and use Edge crease <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: support loops]

Make final object smooth.

[image: Smooth object]

Comment: Ideal but I wouldn't recommend adding a subsurf modifier so early when modeling a hard surface object.

Comment: Funny, I always add subsurf one of the first things I do. Is it just your preference or do you have a technical argument against it?

Comment: A bit of both. While you can toggle this on/off, even when modeling organic objects, it's best to flush your shape out as much as possible before using subsurf even to see how it's coming along. Having everything smoothed makes it harder to add certain details to a model and if you repeatedly toggle on/off you can lose track of scale etc. -- _All that being said, if you know what you are doing, fine, do whatever :) but not something I would recommend to a beginner._

Comment: A valid point, that last remark. :)